# Alfresco: Hide "General Info" section in workflow-details form

Tags: xml, forms, workflow, alfresco

I am trying to configure the form displayed when I view the details of a workflow. I can generate a custom form, but the "General Info" sections which comes with the default form is still displayed. I do not want it to be displayed. My configuration is as follows:

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="vorwf:allocateDocumentProperties" replace="true">
    <forms>
        <form id="workflow-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
                <show id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
                <show id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
                <show id="vorwf:author" />
                <show id="vorwf:reviewer" />
                <show id="vorwf:approver" />
                <show id="vorwf:prevComment" />
                <show id="packageItems" />
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
                <show id="transitions" />
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="information" appearance="title" label="Workflow Information" />
                <set id="wfinfo" appearance="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl" />
                <set id="assignees" appearance="title" label="Assignees" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/3-column-set.ftl" />
                <set id="items" appearance="title" label="Workflow Documents" />
                <set id="outcome" appearance="" />
                <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label="Message" set="information" read-only="true">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" label="Due Date" set="wfinfo" read-only="true">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl">
                        <control-param name="showTime">false</control-param>
                        <control-param name="submitTime">false</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="bpm:workflowPriority" label="Priority" set="wfinfo" read-only="true">
                    <control template="controls/workflow/priority.ftl" />
                </field>
                <field id="vorwf:prevComment" label="Comments from workflow initiator" set="wfinfo" read-only="true">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="saveLineBreaks">true</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="vorwf:author" label="Book Captain" set="assignees">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl" /><!--authority.ftl used for selecting assignees-->
                </field>
                <field id="vorwf:reviewer" label="Reviewer" set="assignees" >
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl" />
                </field>
                <field id="vorwf:approver" label="Authoriser" set="assignees" >
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/authority.ftl" />
                </field>
                <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
                <field id="bpm:comment" label="Comments" set="outcome" >    
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="saveLineBreaks">true</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>
                <field id="transitions" set="outcome" />
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know!

Marcus
[image: Pic showing the current workflow details form configuration - I would like to get rid of the top section]

Comment: can you add screenshot and explain bit more?

Comment: one more thing replace="true" will not work because the task-type is not OOB.

Comment: I've added one to the post. The top section (General Info) is the one I would like to remove

Answer (score 0):

Basically for this you need to remove it from the share webscript.This is not getting loaded from form configuration.

Below is the file which is responsible for loading the `General Info` Section.
Please find comment "Need to remove below html element" and remove that element.
You need to remove code from javascript file also.Because there is an ajax call in javascript file which is setting data on this elements.If you are not updating javacript file that it may r=throw an exception which may stop rendering of form.

### workflow-form.get.html.ftl

```
<@markup id="css" >
   <#-- CSS Dependencies -->
   <#include "../form/form.css.ftl"/>
   <@link href="${url.context}/res/components/workflow/workflow-form.css" group="workflow"/>

   <#-- Global Folder Picker (req'd by Copy/Move To) -->
   <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/global-folder.css" />

   <#-- Cloud Authentication -->
   <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/cloud/cloud-auth-form.css" />
   <#-- Cloud Folder Picker -->
   <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/cloud/cloud-folder-picker.css" />
   <#-- Cloud Sync Status -->
   <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${page.url.context}/res/modules/cloud/cloud-sync-status.css" />
</@>

<@markup id="js">
   <#-- JavaScript Dependencies -->
   <#include "../form/form.js.ftl"/>
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/components/workflow/workflow-form.js" group="workflow"/>

   <@script src="${url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/doclib-actions.js" group="workflow" />
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/modules/simple-dialog.js" group="workflow"/>
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/global-folder.js" group="workflow" />
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/cloud-folder.js" group="workflow" />
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/modules/cloud-auth.js" group="workflow" />
   <@script src="${url.context}/res/components/common/common-component-style-filter-chain.js" group="workflow"/>
</@>

<@markup id="widgets">
   <@createWidgets group="workflow"/>
</@>

<@markup id="html">
   <@uniqueIdDiv>
      <#assign el=args.htmlid?html>
      <div id="${el}-body" class="workflow-form"></div>
      <div class="hidden">
      <#--
       The workflow details page form is actually a form display of the workflow's start task AND data from the workflow itself.
       The approach taken to mix all this information is described in the Alfresco.WorkflowForm javascript class.
      -->
         <#-- Will be inserted in the top of the form after its been loaded through ajax -->
         <div id="${el}-summary-form-section">
            <h3>
               ${msg("header.workflowSummary")}
            </h3>
            <div class="workflow-summary-buttons">
               <button id="${el}-viewWorkflowDiagram" class="hidden">${msg("button.viewWorkflowDiagram")}</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-element-background-color form-element-border summary">
               <div class="summary-icons">
                  <h3>${msg("label.general")}</h3>
                  <div id="${el}-statusSummary" class="status"></div>
                  <div id="${el}-dueSummary" class="due"></div>
                  <div id="${el}-prioritySummary" class="priority"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="recent-task form-element-border">
                  <div class="yui-gc">
                     <div class="yui-u first">
                        <h3>${msg("label.mostRecentlyCompletedTask")}</h3>
                     </div>
                     <div class="yui-u current-tasks">
                        <a href="#current-tasks">${msg("link.viewCurrentTasks")}</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                     <a id="${el}-recentTaskTitle" href=""></a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="yui-gb">
                     <div class="yui-u first">
                        <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.completedOn")}:</span>
                        <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-recentTaskCompletedOn"></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="yui-u">
                        <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.completedBy")}:</span>
                        <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-recentTaskCompletedBy"></span>
                     </div>
                     <div class="yui-u">
                        <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.outcome")}:</span>
                        <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-recentTaskOutcome"></span>
                     </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="yui-gf">
                     <div class="yui-u first avatar">
                        <img id="${el}-recentTaskOwnersAvatar" src="" alt="${msg("label.avatar")}">
                     </div>
                     <div class="yui-u">
                        <div id="${el}-recentTaskOwnersCommentLink"></div>
                        <div id="${el}-recentTaskOwnersComment" class="task-comment form-element-border"></div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

         </div>

         <#-- Will be inserted above "More Info" in the form after its been loaded through ajax -->
         <#--Need to remove below html element-->

         <div id="${el}-general-form-section">
            <div class="set">
               <div class="set-title">${msg("header.generalInfo")}</div>
               <div class="form-field">
                  <div class="viewmode-field">
                     <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.title")}:</span>
                     <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-title"></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-field">
                  <div class="viewmode-field">
                     <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.description")}:</span>
                     <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-description"></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="yui-gb">
                  <div class="yui-u first">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.startedBy")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-startedBy"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="yui-u">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.due")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-due"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="yui-u">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.completed")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-completed"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="yui-gb">
                  <div class="yui-u first">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.started")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-started"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="yui-u">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.priority")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-priority"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="yui-u">
                     <div class="form-field">
                        <div class="viewmode-field">
                           <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.status")}:</span>
                           <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-status"></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-field">
                  <div class="viewmode-field">
                     <span class="viewmode-label">${msg("label.message")}:</span>
                     <span class="viewmode-value" id="${el}-message"></span>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>

         <#-- Will be inserted below "Items" in the form after its been loaded through ajax -->
         <div id="${el}-currentTasks-form-section" class="current-tasks">
            <a name="current-tasks"></a>
            <h3>${msg("header.currentTasks")}</h3>
            <div class="form-element-background-color"></div>
         </div>

         <#-- Will be inserted in the bottom of the form after its been loaded through ajax -->
         <div id="${el}-workflowHistory-form-section" class="workflow-history">
            <h3>${msg("header.history")}</h3>
            <div class="form-element-background-color"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </@>
</@>
```

Comment: I've managed to find and edit the .ftl file, but I cannot figure out which javascript file I need to change. Could you advise me further on this?

Comment: workflow-form.js is the file.I think the function name in which you need to do changes is onWorkflowFormLoaded.