# alfresco workflow details page - how to hide parameters?

Tags: workflow, share, alfresco

I'm having issues and questions regarding the workflow details form. From what I've understood so far, modifications can mainly be done by modifying **share-config-custom.xml**, by adding a form-tag looking something like this (tried a number of variations):

```html
<form id="workflow-details">
     <field-visibility>
          <show id="cmpny:processId" />
          <hide id="cmpny:title" />
          <hide id="cmpny:description" />
          <hide id="packageItems" />
          <hide id="cmpny:reason"/>
          <hide id="cmpny:review"/>
          <hide id="cmpny:deadline" />                                  
          <hide id="cmpny:customReviewOutcome"/>                              
     </field-visibility>            
     <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label="Overview" />
                <set id="main" appearance="title" label="Description" />
                <field id="cmpny:processId" set="main" label="Process-ID"/>
     </appearance>
</form>
```

I have mainly tried copying the working form from one of the tasks and modifying it, giving it its own config-tag or added it to one existing one under the task's forms-tag, but nothing seems to work - at all. Whatever I do, no changes appear.

My main expectation is to having at least something appear, but no visible changes can be detected. I found this post:

[Alfresco: Hide "General Info" section in workflow-details form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267371/alfresco-hide-general-info-section-in-workflow-details-form)

where the person in question at least managed to achieve some differences this way. I also want to modify the general-info, but that is another matter for another day. For the moment, I want to be able to modify the form displayed.

Apart from this, I wonder - most instructions on how to achieve this is very sparse. Most just seem to say "add a form with id=workflow-details to a task config-tag", and the form should appear once that specific task has been completed.

My questions are the following:

- **Apart from using a form with id="workflow-details" and adding it to a task's config-tag, is there anything more to it, in order to make it work?**
- **Is there a way to make the form in question appear no matter the latest task?**

** **EDIT** **

This is the latest code, unfiltered and cut straight from share-config-custom.xml.

```html
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="cmpny:workflowModel_acceptreject">
      <forms>       
            <form id="workflow-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cmpny:processId0" />
                <show id="cmpny:title0" />
                <show id="cmpny:description0" />
                <show id="packageItems" />
                <show id="cmpny:reason0"/>
                <show id="cmpny:granskningsretur0"/>
                <show id="cmpny:deadline0" />                                   
                <show id="cmpny:customReviewOutcome0"/>                               
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label="Översikt" />
                <set id="main" appearance="title" label="Beskrivning" />
                <set id="items" appearance="title" label="Information" />
                <set id="other" appearance="title" label="Beslut" />
                <field id="cmpny:processId0" set="main" label="Process-ID"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>
                <field id="cmpny:title0" set="main" label="Uppgiftsrubrik"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>                        
                <field id="cmpny:description0" set="main" label="Meddelande"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>                           
                <field id="packageItems" set="main" label="Bifogade Filer"/>

                <field id="cmpny:reason0" set="main" label="Kommentar">
                    <control
                        template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="rows">4</control-param>
                        <control-param name="columns">8</control-param>
                        <control-param name="maxLength">5000</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>


                <field id="cmpny:deadline0" set="items" label="Förfallodatum"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>
                <field id="cmpny:granskningsretur0" set="items" label="Granskning begärd"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>

                <field id="cmpny:customReviewOutcome0" label="Utfall" set="other">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl" />
                </field>            
            </appearance>
        </form>
         <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="cmpny:processId0" />
                <show id="cmpny:title0" />
                <show id="cmpny:description0" />
                <show id="packageItems" />
                <show id="cmpny:reason0"/>
                <show id="cmpny:granskningsretur0"/>
                <show id="cmpny:deadline0" />                                   
                <show id="cmpny:customReviewOutcome0"/>                               
            </field-visibility>

            <appearance>
                <set id="" appearance="title" label="Översikt" />
                <set id="main" appearance="title" label="Beskrivning" />
                <set id="items" appearance="title" label="Information" />
                <set id="other" appearance="title" label="Beslut" />
                <field id="cmpny:processId0" set="main" label="Process-ID"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>
                <field id="cmpny:title0" set="main" label="Uppgiftsrubrik"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>                        
                <field id="cmpny:description0" set="main" label="Meddelande"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>                           
                <field id="packageItems" set="main" label="Bifogade Filer"/>

                <field id="cmpny:reason0" set="main" label="Kommentar">
                    <control
                        template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                        <control-param name="rows">4</control-param>
                        <control-param name="columns">8</control-param>
                        <control-param name="maxLength">5000</control-param>
                    </control>
                </field>


                <field id="cmpny:deadline0" set="items" label="Förfallodatum"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>
                <field id="cmpny:granskningsretur0" set="items" label="Granskning begärd"><control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl"/></field>

                <field id="cmpny:customReviewOutcome0" label="Utfall" set="other">
                    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl" />
                </field>            
            </appearance>
         </form>

      </forms>
    </config>
```

Screenshot (Only one, but the workflow-details-tag literally makes ZERO difference - screenshots are identical down to the pixel).
Perhaps at least worth mentioning is that I've also meddled some with the webscript, but I've checked that it isn't the cause.
[Screenshot link here, can't add it directly apparently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWqKD.png)

I've tried multiple combinations, putting it in different tasks, shaving the parameters down to a bare minimum - nothing works. To just make it clear - ANY difference is what I'm aiming for at the moment - just getting anything to stick.

** **EDIT 2** **

Clarified screenshot here.

[Second, enhanced screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjRie.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is the way you can add items in workflow details page

```
<field-visibility>
   <show id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" />              
</field-visibility>

<appearance>
   <set id="docSubDetails" label="Document Details" 
 template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>                
</appearance>
```

or Hide

```
<field-visibility>
       <hide id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" />              
</field-visibility>
```

Full code

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="someWorkflow:peerReviewerTask">
    <forms>
        <form>
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:documentLocation" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:documentName" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:author" />
                <show id="bpm:assignees" />
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:peerReviewTaskOutcome" />                
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="docSubDetails" label="Document Details" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
                <set id="docAuthor" appearance="title" label="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:documentLocation" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:documentName" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>      
                <field id="someWorkflow:author" set="docAuthor" label="Author" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="bpm:assignees" set="docAuthor" label="QC Reviewer(s)" read-only="true"/>              
              </field>  
            </appearance>
        </form>
        <form id="workflow-details">
            <field-visibility>
                <show id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:documentLocation" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:documentName" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:author" />
                <show id="bpm:assignees" />
                <show id="bpm:comment" />
                <show id="someWorkflow:peerReviewTaskOutcome" />                  
            </field-visibility>
            <appearance>
                <set id="docSubDetails" label="Document Details" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
                <set id="docAuthor" appearance="title" label="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:VersionNumber" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:documentLocation" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="someWorkflow:documentName" set="docSubDetails" read-only="true"/>      
                <field id="someWorkflow:author" set="docAuthor" label="Author" read-only="true"/>
                <field id="bpm:assignees" set="docAuthor" label="QC Reviewer(s)" read-only="true"/>
            </appearance>
        </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

Comment: I'm thankful for the quick answer, but what exactly am I doing different? Mixing show/hide, not using enough appearence settings...? To me this is more or less the same as the example I gave.

Comment: i am bit confused, what exactly needed. what you want to show or hide? can you please give more information on this.

Comment: also you need to create <config evaluator="task-type" condition="somworkflow:Form5"> as a parent tag, inside add <form id="workflow-details"> as a child element

Comment: Basically, I want to show or hide anything. Just make it show ANY difference. I've tried a dozen different configurations but none seem to work :( The workflow detail page looks exactly the same regardless of what I'm adding (although the task forms within the same document respond just fine to changes). 

As i've stated above, I did put the <form id= ... > child element within a config parent tag, I tried both giving it a duplicate tag and also putting it in an existing tag. Neither worked.

Are there any other rules that I've missed perhaps?

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot to your question - with required changes and without changes

Comment: ok, now tell me, from screenshot what you intended to hide or show?

Comment: Added a second, more clarified screenshot. What I want to do is just alter the form used in workflow-details. I have seen and understood the proposed method and it is indeed what I want to use - the only problem is that it isn't working for some unknown reason.

Comment: @henrikr, it is possible based on your second screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Workflow summary displays workflow / task details from start-task details only. So I have shared workflow model and share configuration also.

**Workflow Model**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<model xmlns='http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0' name='workflowns:model'>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <imports>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" prefix="d"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/system/1.0" prefix="sys"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0" prefix="cm"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/site/1.0" prefix="st"/>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0" prefix="bpm" />
  </imports>
  <namespaces>
    <namespace uri="workflowns.model" prefix="workflowns"/>
  </namespaces>
  <types>

    <type name="workflowns:Form0">
       <title>Initiator Task</title>
       <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
       <mandatory-aspects>
       <aspect>bpm:assignee</aspect> 
       <aspect>workflowns:reviewerAspect</aspect> 
       <aspect>workflowns:approverAspect</aspect>   
       <aspect>workflowns:finalapproverAspect</aspect>   
       <aspect>workflowns:notesLabel</aspect> 
          <aspect>workflowns:Aspect1</aspect>
          <aspect>workflowns:Aspect3</aspect>
       </mandatory-aspects>
    </type>
    ....
    </model>
```

**Share Custom Configuration**

```
<!-- Workflow details page-->
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="workflowns:startTask">
    <forms>
      <form>
        <field-visibility>
          <show id="workflowns:documentname" />
          <show id="workflowns:documentversion" />
          <show id="workflowns:pathorlinktothedocument" />
          <show id="workflowns:customerno" />
          <show id="workflowns:projectno" />
          <show id="workflowns:author" />
          <show id="workflowns:reviewer" />
          <show id="workflowns:approver" />
          <show id="workflowns:finalapprover" />
          <show id="workflowns:initiatorcomment" />
          <show id="bpm:taskId" />
          <show id="bpm:status" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
        <set id="docDetails" appearance="title" label="Document Details"/>
        <set id="docSubDetails" label="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
        <set id="docAuthor" appearance="title" label="Author" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
        <set id="docReviewer" appearance="title" label="Reviewers" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
        <set id="docApprover" appearance="title" label="Approvers" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
        <set id="docFinalapprover" appearance="title" label="Final Approvers" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl"/>
          <field id="workflowns:documentname" set="docDetails" label="Document Name">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:documentversion" set="docDetails" label="Document Version">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:pathorlinktothedocument" set="docDetails" label="Path or Link to the document">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:customerno" set="docSubDetails" label="Customer Number">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:projectno" set="docSubDetails" label="Project Number">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:author" set="docAuthor" label="Author">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:reviewer" set="docReviewer" label="Reviewer">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:approver" set="docApprover" label="Approver">
          </field>
          <field id="workflowns:finalapprover" set="docFinalapprover" label="Final Approver">
          </field>
        </appearance>
      </form>
    </forms>
</config>
```

[image: Workflow History Page Customisation]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no :(  In my eyes, this is more or less what I am doing now. Apart from different fields, of course. What I need is to hear what exactly is causing (or at least could potentially could) cause this issue - namely what is preventing my form to be used. Some condition not listed in the documentation perhaps, or some obscure limitation in the structure. I have literally no idea what is causing this, and I've reviewed virtually every piece of material mentioning this, to no avail.